# How do I iterate over a list of variables and return new variables?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list, variables, survey

Ok, I'm very new with python so there's a possibility I'm going about this all wrong.

That said, I'm working with survey data and the survey responses are coded so that there is one spreadsheet with response codes to questions and another defining those codes. I've converted the spreadsheet of definitions of the codes into about a dozen pandas dataframes corresponding to each question that look like this:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Definition for 1 |
| 2 | Definition for 2 |
| 3 | Definition for 3 |

Each of these dataframes is assigned to a variable with a name like Q1_df, Q2_df, etc. I want to iterate over a list of all those dataframes, converting them into dictionaries that look like this: {"1": "Definition for 1, "2": "Definition for 2", "3" : "Definition for 3}. I want to run through the whole survey response spreadsheet and convert each response into the corresponding value from the dictionary.

Is there a way to iterate over my list that looks like this: [Q1_df, Q2_df, ... Q14_df] and have an output list that looks like this: [Q1_dict, Q2_dict, ... Q14_dict]?

If there's a simpler way to do this I'd love to hear it too.

Thank you all so much!

I'm lost as to what to try because I don't know how to iterate over a list of variables to produce new variables with changed names.

Comment: You should never create variables programmatically, this is considered very bad practice. Use a container (list or dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `lst` the input list, use a list comprehension, [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
lst = [Q1_df, Q2_df, Q14_df]

out = [df.set_index('Key')['Value'].to_dict()
       for df in lst]
```

Then access each dictionary in the output by position:

```
out[0]
```

If you really want a name, create a dictionary:

```
out = {f'Q{i}': df.set_index('Key')['Value'].to_dict()
       for i, df in enumerate(lst, start=1)}
```

Then: `out['Q1']`